# String-numeric variable name in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I want to create a loop from `i := 1` to `n` which takes a random number from the `procedure` and assigns its value to the variables named `x1,x2,x3,x4...xn`

So it could look like this:

```
  for i:=1 to 100 do begin
     GenerateRandomNumber(x); // this procedure gives the updated value of x
     xi := x;
  end
```

I want to solve it by creating an `array[1..n] of string` and then assign this random number to the `ith` element of the array. But to be honest, I don't like this solution. Is there any faster way? I was thinking about concatenating a string with a number, or converting "x" (the string) to a number and then somehow merging it with the consecutive values of `i`. What do you think?

Comment: What makes you think this is faster?  What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: That's not very clear. The most costly is the convertion from the number to the string representation. If performances are a concern then two possibilities: If you're sure that the string representations will all be used than cache them otherwise just do the convertion lazily: when needed.  About storing there is no so many ways to do that: array, list or associative array. In your case, array is recommended. List are good when the content is modified and associative arrays when the two data are not related. This is not the case here as you have an index, a number and its representation.

Comment: A RTTI lookup of a variable might be more expensive than constructing the string, since it might require several string comparisons. Not that it matters, RTTI of non published fields in FPC is in alpha only in a separate branch. Anyway, use an array or a class, this is the wrong way of thinking, in a compiled language, names of variables, functions and types are considered lost after compilation. The exceptions (RTTI) are costly, bulky and relatively new.